# Error: It looks like your application or one of its dependencies is using i18n after recompile angular 13.1

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working on an Angular project 13.0.1
I just updated it to `13.1.0`
my `package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "gptk-total-system-angular",
  "version": "00.09.17",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --open",
    "start-es": "node ./replace.build.js && ng serve --open --configuration=es",
    "build": "node ./replace.build.js && ng build --configuration=production --build-optimizer --optimization --extract-licenses=false",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^13.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^13.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^13.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^13.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^13.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^13.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^13.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^13.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^13.1.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^13.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^2.0.2",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^23.1.0",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "js-sha512": "^0.8.0",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.21",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "mds.persian.datetime": "^1.4.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.1.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^13.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^13.1.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^13.1.0",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^5.1.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.10.2",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/lodash-es": "^4.17.5",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.9",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.10.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^7.0.0",
    "javascript-obfuscator": "^2.19.1",
    "karma": "^6.3.9",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "replace-in-file": "^6.3.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.4.0",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "~4.4.4",
    "webpack-obfuscator": "^3.5.0"
  }
}
```

It's OK and when I type `npm run start` it started without any problems, but whenever I change any code and code recompiled I get the following error in some pages !:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: It looks like your application or one of its dependencies is using i18n.
Angular 9 introduced a global `$localize()` function that needs to be loaded.
Please run `ng add @angular/localize` from the Angular CLI.
(For non-CLI projects, add `import '@angular/localize/init';` to your `polyfills.ts` file.
For server-side rendering applications add the import to your `main.server.ts` file.)
Error: It looks like your application or one of its dependencies is using i18n.
Angular 9 introduced a global `$localize()` function that needs to be loaded.
Please run `ng add @angular/localize` from the Angular CLI.
(For non-CLI projects, add `import '@angular/localize/init';` to your `polyfills.ts` file.
For server-side rendering applications add the import to your `main.server.ts` file.)
    at _global.$localize (core.mjs:28615)
    at new PmEquipmentTaskCheckListHistoryComponent (pm-equipment-task-check-list-history.component.ts:32)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.PmEquipmentTaskCheckListHistoryComponent_Factory [as factory] (pm-equipment-task-check-list-history.component.ts:22)
    at getNodeInjectable (core.mjs:3549)
    at instantiateRootComponent (core.mjs:10144)
    at createRootComponent (core.mjs:12245)
    at ComponentFactory.create (core.mjs:21566)
    at ViewContainerRef.createComponent (core.mjs:22812)
    at RouterOutlet.activateWith (router.mjs:2520)
    at ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes (router.mjs:2160)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1213)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1167)
    at zone.js:1279
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:25437)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:582)
```

I have `polyfills.ts` as follows and my code was OK before Updating!

```json
/***************************************************************************************************
 * Load `$localize` onto the global scope - used if i18n tags appear in Angular templates.
 */
import '@angular/localize/init';
/**
 * This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
 * You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
 *
 * This file is divided into 2 sections:
 *   1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are sorted by browsers.
 *   2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be loaded before your main
 *      file.
 *
 * The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that
 * automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera),
 * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
 *
 * Learn more in https://angular.io/guide/browser-support
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

/**
 * By default, zone.js will patch all possible macroTask and DomEvents
 * user can disable parts of macroTask/DomEvents patch by setting following flags
 * because those flags need to be set before `zone.js` being loaded, and webpack
 * will put import in the top of bundle, so user need to create a separate file
 * in this directory (for example: zone-flags.ts), and put the following flags
 * into that file, and then add the following code before importing zone.js.
 * import './zone-flags';
 *
 * The flags allowed in zone-flags.ts are listed here.
 *
 * The following flags will work for all browsers.
 *
 * (window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true; // disable patch requestAnimationFrame
 * (window as any).__Zone_disable_on_property = true; // disable patch onProperty such as onclick
 * (window as any).__zone_symbol__UNPATCHED_EVENTS = ['scroll', 'mousemove']; // disable patch specified eventNames
 *
 *  in IE/Edge developer tools, the addEventListener will also be wrapped by zone.js
 *  with the following flag, it will bypass `zone.js` patch for IE/Edge
 *
 *  (window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;
 *
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js';  // Included with Angular CLI.


/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */
```

Comment: Did you already try running `ng add @angular/localize`? What's the result?

Comment: of course yes, the result: `Skipping installation: Package already installed
Nothing to be done.`

Comment: Also a few notes: 1) after changing the `package.json` you should run `npm install`. 2) The [official upgrade guide](https://update.angular.io/) suggests you to run `npx @angular/cli update @angular/core @angular/cli`. Sadly atm that’s all I can think of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `polyfills.ts`, comment `import '@angular/localize/init';` and add `import '../node_modules/@angular/localize/init';`

```json
// import '@angular/localize/init';
import '../node_modules/@angular/localize/init';
```

Comment: can you explain why does it work? when i debug my app with intellij sometimes i get this error and with your solution it's gone.

Comment: I don't know why! I installed `@angular/localize` package and config it as well, But I get the error. I doubt to `import '@angular/localize/init';` so I changed to `import '../node_modules/@angular/localize/init';` and it worked

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I follow the suggestion from the developer options that said I must install localize by using this command:

```
ng add @angular/localize
```

Then I restart the IDE I used (VS code). And everything was working perfectly.
I noticed that it updated the polyfills.ts file, but I didn't make any manual changes to the file.

Answer (score 1):

I am aware this is already answered; however, for me, the other answer didn't work for Angular 14 but this worked:

```
import '@angular/localize/init'
```

Above was added in the polyfills.ts file, in project which is throwing error.

Comment: i had to add this to my cypress component test to solve the same error